# Anchor Tag Smooth Transition

Tags: javascript

Right now my menu item will scroll to my anchor tag **< front >#tag1,** without a problem. However I do not like how "jumpy" it is. I would like a smoother scroll affect?

I found this module: https://www.drupal.org/project/scroll_to_destination_anchors .

I have jquery and javascript enabled, but I can't seem to get a smoother affect. Any Help? I am using Drupal 7 core.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://www.drupal.org/node/2492033 and check if your links to anchors are with or without a path. You could maybe use [Void Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/void_menu) to make special links without path.

As an alternative to this module I recommend to take a look at: [Jquery Localscroll](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_localscroll)